# Split a log file keeping data integrity using a delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a huge log file to be divided into files of approximately 1MB each.
I can use `split` command, but I would break a log entry by half, or even work I could split in the middle of a line.

How can you split such a file using a simple and elegant command? (a complex script wouldn't be a solution).

For the following case the split would be done just after the token '===='

```
====
Log entry 1 line 1
Log entry 1 line 2 
Log entry 1 line 3
====
Log entry 2 line 1 
Log entry 2 line n
====
```

Comment: Isn't this what the the `-C` argument of `split` does?

Comment: No. -C man entry: "put at most SIZE bytes of line per output file".
I'm looking for a solution to split a certain number of lines, but spliting only after a certain token.

Comment: I haven't tried it but that `-C` definition *sounded* to me like it splits at `SIZE bytes` but at the line level. Which should mean that it stops at the end of the last full line that fits within your `SIZE bytes` but that would need to be tested.

Answer (score 3):

csplit command can be used to split based on a pattern.

For example,

```
csplit -f PREFIX -n 2 large_file '/====/' '{*}'
```

This would split the file at '===='

Names the generated files as PREFIX01, PREFIX02

{*} specifies split into as many times as the pattern shows up in the input file.

There are other options to fine tune the way output files are generated.
You can put an integer after /====/ to control whether to split exactly at token, before or after.